# problem when varying the defaultValue of an input:number reack-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am creating a modal window that offers other options to the user to vary quantities through an input and some buttons to increase or decrease the quantity, all this is being handled with the react-hook-form functions.

```
export const ModalCart = ({ show, id, amount, setHandleConfigModal }) => {
    
    const api = new FormService();
    const { handleSubmit, register, setValue, getValues, formState: { isSubmitting } } = useForm()

    const onSubmit = async (formData) => {
        try {
            console.log({...formData, id})
            setHandleConfigModal({ show: false })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Modal
            show={ show }
            onHide={ () => setHandleConfigModal({ show: false }) }
        >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Handle the Amount</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            
            <Modal.Body>
                <Form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
                    <div className="d-flex gap-2 justify-content-between">
                        <div>
                            <Button
                                className="btn btn-outline-dark px-3 ms-2"
                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                                onClick={ () => setValue( 'amount', Number(getValues('amount')) - 1 ) }
                            >
                                +
                            </Button>
                        </div>

                        <div className="w-100">
                            <Form.Control
                                type="number"
                                placeholder="0"
                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                                defaultValue={ amount}
                                min={0}
                                {...register('amount')}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <Button
                                className="btn btn-outline-dark px-3 me-2"
                                disabled={ isSubmitting }
                                onClick={ () => setValue( 'amount', Number(getValues('amount')) + 1 ) }
                            >
                                -
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <Button 
                        disabled={ isSubmitting }
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-primary px-3 me-2 mt-2"
                    > 
                        Save
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

**first shipment: amount = 15**
[image]

output submit
{ amount:15, id:2 }

**first shipment: the amount should be = 2**
[image]

output submit expected
{ amount:2, id:2 }

output submit received
{ amount:15, id:2 }

The problem I have is that when sending the first quantity to the modal through the props, it is correctly assigned to the input, but after sending another quantity again, the input stays with the previous value. If someone could help me with this problem, I am Newbie would appreciate your help.